# How much RAM to buy?

Tags: eosjs, eosio.token

How can one determine the amount of RAM to buy for a new account and for regular transfer actions?

The page here recommends 4K of RAM:
https://support.bancor.network/hc/en-us/articles/360018325291-What-is-RAM-CPU-and-NET-on-EOS

Is this a hardcoded value or can this be determined from an API call or some routine?

Once the account is created, how much RAM does an account need to have to be able to successfully submit transfer actions?

Answer (score 0):

there's no hardcoded value that enforces the amount of resources needed to create and use an account. and there's no function that you can use to find out the amount of resources needed for creating and using an account.
the amount of RAM needed to create an account can be inferred from the code that defines the structures needed to store an account. after you create and account you need CPU and NET as well to be able to transact with that account (send tokens for example). the amount of resources needed to transact with your account it depends on how much the network is congested and how active you want to be with your account.